# Extracting data from the $matches hashtable after a Powershell Regeg -match

Tags: regex, powershell, hashtable

I've already spent over an hour trying to get a simple RegEx to work.  My pattern is working, and I'm getting back the $Matches which as I have read is supposed to be a hash table.  So how do I get what I've captured?

Code:

```
   cls 
   $keyword = "this is a 12345 test" 
   $pattern = "\d{5}"
   $keyword -match $pattern 
   $returnZipcode = "ERROR" 
   Write-Host "GetZipCodeFromKeyword RegEx `$Matches.Count=$($Matches.Count)" 
   $Matches | Out-String | Write-Host
   Write-Host "`$Matches[0].Value=$($Matches[0].Value)"
   Write-Host "`$Matches.Get_Item('0')=$($Matches.Get_Item("0"))"
   if ($Matches.Count -gt 0) 
      {
         $returnZipcode = $Matches[0].Value
      }

   # this is how hash tables work - why doesn't same work with the $Matches variable? 
   $states = @{"Washington" = "Olympia"; "Oregon" = "Salem"; California = "Sacramento"}
   $states | Out-String | Write-Host
   Write-Host "`$states.Get_Item('Oregon')=$($states.Get_Item("Oregon"))"
```

Run time results:

```
Name                           Value  
----                           -----  
0                              12345  

$Matches[0].Value=
$Matches.Get_Item('0')=

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Washington                     Olympia
Oregon                         Salem  
California                     Sacramento 

$states.Get_Item('Oregon')=Salem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Matches` is just a hashtable, the `Name` and `Value` columns aren't properties of the elements. `Name` is just the key, `Value` is the value.

```
PS C:\> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              12345


PS C:\> $Matches[0]
12345
```

If you wish you can use `Get_Item`, but the key in `$Matches` is an integer, not a string:

```
PS C:\> $states.Get_Item('Oregon')
Salem
PS C:\> $Matches.Get_Item(0)
12345
```

Unlike some other languages not all hashtable keys have to be strings and Powershell mostly won't convert numbers to and from strings unless you tell it to.

Comment: Thanks, just posted follow-up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194148/powershell-match-in-function-gets-extra-true-false-when-returned  I thought the true/false was coming back as part of hashtable, still not sure why.