# Powershell -match in function - gets extra true/false when returned

Tags: regex, powershell, hashtable

Why do I get the extract "True" or "False" (when all I want to get back is just the zip code) on the result of this function:

```
Function GetZipCodeFromKeyword([String] $keyword)
{
   $pattern = "\d{5}"
   $keyword -match $pattern 
   $returnZipcode = "ERROR" 
   #Write-Host "GetZipCodeFromKeyword RegEx `$Matches.Count=$($Matches.Count)" 
   if ($Matches.Count -gt 0) 
      {
         $returnZipcode = $Matches[0] 
      }

   Write-Host "`$returnZipcode=$returnZipcode"
   return $returnZipcode 
}

cls
$testKeyword = "Somewhere in 77562 Texas "
$zipcode = GetZipCodeFromKeyword $testKeyword 
Write-Host "Zip='$zipcode' from keyword=$testKeyword" 

Write-Host " "
$testKeyword = "Somewhere in Dallas Texas "
$zipcode = GetZipCodeFromKeyword $testKeyword 
Write-Host "Zip='$zipcode' from keyword=$testKeyword"
```

Results of run time:

```
$returnZipcode=77562
Zip='True 77562' from keyword=Somewhere in 77562 Texas 

$returnZipcode=12345
Zip='False 12345' from keyword=Somewhere in Dallas Texas
```

Comment: because $keyword -match $pattern = True

Comment: `return` doesn't mean what you think it means in powershell. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286164/powershell-function-return-value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line `$keyword -match $pattern` returns `$True` if the pattern matches, `$False` otherwise. Since you don't do anything else with the value it is output from the function.

Try:

```
Function GetZipCodeFromKeyword([String] $keyword)
{
   $pattern = "\d{5}"
   $returnZipcode = "ERROR" 
   if ($keyword -match $pattern)
      {
         $returnZipcode = $Matches[0] 
      }

   Write-Host "`$returnZipcode=$returnZipcode"
   return $returnZipcode 
}
```

Any value output from the function becomes part of the result whether you explictly write it with `Write-Output` or return it with `return`, or just implicitly have a pipeline that outputs a result.

If you don't want a pipeline output to output from the function assign it to a variable. e.g.

```
$m = $keyword -match $pattern
```

or redirect it:

```
$keyword -match $pattern >$null
```

or:

```
$keyword -match $pattern | Out-Null
```

or send it to another output stream:

```
Write-Verbose ($keyword -match $pattern)
```

which leaves you scope to make it visible by setting `$VerbosePreference='Continue'` (or make your function into a cmdlet and use the `-Verbose` flag when calling it). Though in this last case I would still assign it to a variable first:

```
$m = $keyword -match $pattern
Write-Verbose "GetZipCodeFromKeyword RegEx match: $m"
```

Comment: So I'm getting an array back, even though I specifically did a return on just $returnZipCode?  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Okay, this seems to work:  "$isMatch = $keyword -match $pattern" - I guess that keeps the true/false from being returned, and "swallows it" so to speak.